# MySql Inner join based on non empty columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    I have Two tables :
    Table1, Table2
```

I have to write a SQL query which has inner join on three columns based
on <> 0 condition
on these tables.
My condition is

```
    if(table1.ID != 0), then inner join on table1.ID = table2.ID else,

    if(table1.MemberID != 0), then inner join on table1.MemberID = table2.MemberID else,

    inner join on table1.PersonID = table2.PersonID
```

Comment: you sure that you need inner join here?
left join can handle situations where you have non existent values

Comment: @Goran Stuc : Yes I need inner join in this case. I have to match both the fields.

Comment: why dont you use join with OR for each conditions

Comment: @timus I dont know how to use OR condition. It would be great if you could help me write one query for above and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional statement (case when for example) in a join clause.

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on 
            (case when 
                 t1.ID != 0 
                 then t1.ID =t2.Id
                 else
                 case when t1.MemberId !=0 
                      then t1.MemberId = t2.MemberId
                      else
                           t1.PersonId = t2.PersonId
                  end
            end)
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca58e/4)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
select * 
from Table1, Table2
where table1.Personid = table2.personId
and (((Table1.id != 0) and  (Table1.id = table2.Id))
or ((Table1.memberid != 0) and (Table1.memberid = table2.memberId)))
```